# Why does PIL reduce the size when saving PNG (from PNG)?

Tags: python, save, png, python-imaging-library

Let cat.png be a PNG image.

```
ls -l cat.png
-rw-r--r--  1 user  user  138198 29 Aug  2012 cat.png
```

Its size in bytes is 138198.
Then, from Python:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('cat.png')
im.save('test-cat.png')
```

And:

```
ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 user  user  138198 29 Aug  2012 cat.png
-rw-r--r--  1 user  user  134105 10 Mar 17:18 test-cat.png
```

The size of the file is smaller.

Now, I am aware [1] that PIL strips out some metadata (e.g.: 'info').
However, if I use the method from [1] to preserve 'info', the
result is:

```
ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  135026 10 Mar 17:23 test-cat-with-info.png
```

What am I missing? Or, better, what is the file created by PIL missing?

Cheers

Refs

[1] http://blog.modp.com/2007/08/python-pil-and-png-metadata-take-2.html

Cat pic

[2] http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png ;)

Comment: Use `pngcheck -vv` on both your files to check (1) if the color model changed; (2) if chunks are removed; and (3) if the compression changed. Wen (1) and (2) are not relevant, (3) means that PILs built-in best-compression guessing algorithm is better than that of the software you used to create it with.

Comment: Thank you. You are right.

The result for test-cat.png (the one saved using PIL):
*No errors detected in test-cat.png (5 chunks, 73.2% compression).*

The result for cat.png:
*No errors detected in cat.png (5 chunks, 72.4% compression).*

It looks like PIL is using the "zlib default compression", whilst the image was originally compressed using "zlib maximum compression" (which is somehow confusing).

I have no way to prevent this happening, but I guess I should mark the question as solved?

Thank you.

Comment: Nice! Don't change your title or question. You can write up your findings as a proper answer (self-answering is specifically allowed), and then self-accept it as well  so it will be marked "solved". Maybe someone can comment on the zlib options as well.